# how to navigate page with voice command in javascript,php,jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to use a voice command to navigate between webpage. I want something for example if I say "1" from the microphone it will direct me to "exp.php" and if i say "2" it will take me to index.php. I have to idea how to come up with that. Need your help. Thanks in advance

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: type "voice command to navigate between web page jquery" into Google.

Comment: Thanks I will go tru the link. I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, you can do this only on Chrome 25+ right now using the [Web Speech API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html). Check out the demonstration here:

https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html